# How can i solve the following SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql

```
select Preacher_Id , Name from Preacher_SkillDetail
where Preacher_Id not in (
      where Preacher_FK from Event_Preacher
      where (@newstartdate <= Start_Date and @newenddate >= Start_Date) 
      or (@newstartdate <= End_Date and @newenddate >= End_Date)
      or (@newstartdate >= End_Date and @newenddate  <= End_Date)
      or (@newstartdate <= Start_Date and @newenddate >= End_Date)
)
```

I want to `bind the output` to an `ropdowncontrol`

how can i do it in c#.net?? i have variables `newstartdate and newenddate as Date`

Comment: @hims056 thanks....but its still not working

Comment: @hims056 it is a sub query.

Comment: Your question consists of multiple parts. Gathering the Data from the database (SqlDataReader), putting the data in an Data Transfer Object and then displaying it in an Dropdown. Iam shure these individual steps are obtainable here on SO or the web.

Comment: If you want to do it in c#, use Linq

Comment: @Kaf - Ah. Didn't notice that.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid i know that but i am learning C#, so i am asking you in this forum!!!

Comment: @user1883122 you can use linq as a part of c#, it simplifies your queries and makes it easier to integrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable GetData() {

    SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString="Put your connection string";


    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = "Your Sql Query Geos here";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        // Log ur error;


    }
    finally {

        connection.Close();
    }
    return dt;
    }
```

Then

```
Dropdownlist.Datasource=GetData();
Dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Specify your TextFiled and ValueField in the control property.

I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the DataTextField and DataValueField of the dropdown list. DataTextField is the field which shows you the elements in your dropdown list. DataValueField holds the ID of those fields. 
If your query returns something like
Peacher_id | Name
1          | Peacher 1
2          | Peacher 2
3          | Peacher 3
Ideally Peacher_Id should bind to the DataValueField and Name should bind to the DataTextField. You can go to dropdownlist properties and set those properties. After that you just have to bind the datasource to the drop down list.

dropdownlist.DataSource = ds;
dropdownlist.DataBind();